Set Execution Name to Step Function Triggered by EventBridge Rule and Target
I am triggering a step function with and event bridge rule and target. I would like to set a custom event name for the state machine. I am able to do this if I use a Scheduled run but not a Rule with a Target.
I have tried multiple options but can't seem to set anything other than the input.
